# Linked List NullPointerException Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list

In LinkedList we normally assign null value to last node and also use this condition to check for the last node.

I am checking for the last node with the same condition either its "next" node link is null or not. But I'm unable to handle NullPointerException when I get null value by the method "getNext".

```
while(lastNode.getNext() != null)
{
lastNode= lastNode.getNext();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this piece of code throwing a NullPointerException?

Comment: Can you paste the code for getNext()?

Comment: @elephont something like `public Node<T> getNext() { return next; }` - that's not what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is a custom implementation of a LinkedList; `java.util.LinkedList` does not have a `getNext()` method.

That said, what you want is:

```
while (current != null) {
    past = current;
    current = current.getNext();
}

return past;
```

I am assuming here that you want to return the last node, and that `past` is a variable of the same type as `current`.